# Не выводит изображение PHP

Tags: php

Не получается вывести изображение. Изображение хранится в формате BLOB.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите скриншоты и покажите код.

Comment: <?php
include "connection.php";
?>
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','',  'Кабинеты') or die       ('Невозможно открыть базу');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Поиск`";
   $result = $conn->query($sql); 
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
      
      

echo 'Индекс: '.$row['Индекс']; 
       echo 'Корпус: '.$row['Корпус'];
    echo 'Этаж: '.$row['Этаж'];
      echo 'Изображение'.$row['Изображение'];
   }
   ?>

Answer (score 1):

Вставка изображения в БД

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName");
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));

$query = "INSERT INTO products (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";  
$qry = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Вывод изображения из БД

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое